# One Click Deploy Solution for my webapp

Tags: javascript, mongodb, heroku

I am looking for a way to provide one click deploy solution for my web app https://github.com/llaske/sugarizer-server .How can I push my app to heroku without merging my webapp and server repo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to merge your git repo, your next best bet is to do a docker deploy.

Basically, you'll create the docker container on your machine using whatever build process you want, and then push said container to Heroku for deployment. You can even make it part of your CI/CD pipe if you prefer.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/container-registry-and-runtime